# How to access to label folder in gmail using java?

Tags: java

We can read messages from gmail inbox but can we read from a label?
If I take the following example from http://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class InboxReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>", "password");
            System.out.println(store);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
            for(Message message:messages) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }

    }

}
```

If I change "inbox" by a label name it's throwing an error: inbox is not found.
Any help, please?

Comment: So in this line:    

    `Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");`

Can you try something like this:

`Folder inbox = store.getFolder("FolderNameGoesHere");`

Comment: With inbox = store.getFolder("folderA"); the result is CONTENT:javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@183967b , the content is not a string

Comment: My problem is resolved with msg.writeTo(System.out);
            msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code which is working for me :

```
store.getFolder("FolderNameGoesHere");

private static Store getConnection() throws MessagingException {
    Properties properties;
    Session session;
    Store store;
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
    session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                          return new PasswordAuthentication("dummy@gmail.com",
                                                                            "dummy");
                                      }
                                  });
    store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect();
    return store;

}

public static boolean isMailReceivedBySubject(String subject,String folder) throws MessagingException {
    Store store = null;
    boolean emailReceived = false;
    try {
        store = getConnection();
        Folder mailFolder = store.getFolder(folder);
        mailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        SearchTerm st = new AndTerm(new SubjectTerm(subject), new BodyTerm(subject));
        Message[] messages = mailFolder.search(st);
        for (Message message : messages) {
            System.out.println("message  : " + message.getSubject());
            if (message.getSubject().contains(subject)) {
                System.out.println("Found the email subject : " + subject);
                emailReceived = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return emailReceived;
    }finally {
        if (store != null) {
            store.close();
        }
    }
}
```